# How is React Navigation rendering the wrong screen here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm stumped by this bizarre behavior in my super-small React Native app that's using React Navigation 5. I have just a login screen and a main tab navigator with a home screen (and a couple placeholder screens). After a successful login I  store the user token in AsyncStorage (and automatically restore the user's state on app start). I have a reducer in in App.js that handles sign-in/sign-out and restoring the token on app launch.

The heart of App.js (following the suggestion from the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) is this Stack.Navigator element:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {console.log(`>> App.js render switch, is isLoggedIn true? >>> ${state.isLoggedIn}`)}
  {state.isLoggedIn ? (
    <Stack.Screen  name="Main" component={MainTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
  ) : (
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
  )}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Here is the bizarre issue: after a successful login, the login screen logic invokes a function passed through a React Context to trigger the "signin" branch of the reducer. That stores the token and sets an isLoggedIn boolean to true. That *should* cause the above ternary to take the first branch and render the MainTabNavigator. Instead it renders the LoginScreen, which already has the user data, so it invokes the reducer again and causes App.js to re-render. The isLoggedIn boolean is still true so it again theoretically takes the first branch here. It goes into a re-render loop until React kills it.

The upshot is that the console.log says isLoggedIn is true but then it does the false branch! However, I've stepped through it and it *is* actually taking the true branch but somehow instead of rendering the MainTabNavigator it renders the LoginScreen. Note that after I clear the error and cause the app to reload, the "restore token" logic works fine and the MainTabNavigator renders.

Anyone have any idea why my app is rendering the login screen on a line that should be rendering the MainTabNavigator?

Oh, also note that I get this warning for calling the setAuth function passed through React Context: `Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.` Not sure if that explains anything. I'm still trying to figure out how to fix it... and how to correctly set state in my Auth Context.

Comment: I put the bulk of App.js, LoginScreen.js, and MainTabNavigator.js up in a gist:
https://gist.github.com/yukster/d79051380f540f523d71573291b87c13

Answer (score 0):

A helpful soul in a React Native Slack channel suggested that instead of checking the `data` in an `if` block (in the LoginScreen), that I use the `onCompleted` callback option provided by Apollo's `useMutation`. So I just moved the work done in that `if` into a function passed as the `onCompleted` and it works great. No warnings, no infinite loop.

I think that somehow that `data` variable returned by Apollo became truthy enough to make that `if` succeed but it was too early to pass the token and cause the app to re-render. It was definitely in a very odd state. I've never seen quite such a confounding bug!